# Handle web service response as XML string or object?

Tags: xml, performance, unmarshalling

I have a REST service client that unmarshals response XMLs to Java objects using JAXB, and a recent requirement change says I need another such client that returns the response, untouched, to anyone who just want the original XML.

My question is, is it better to have:

1. Two functionally identical web service clients that only differ in
   the return type, or
2. One that returns the XML string as-is, and an
       "unmarshal" adapter on top to convert XML to Java objects?  Will
       this cause performance problems since I must store the entire XML as
       a string first?